# Density plot through a single-lined double loop

Tags: plotting

I have a function *f* that is dependent on three parameters ω, κ2 and x:

```
f[ω_, κ2_, 
x_] := (384000.` x κ2 Sqrt[κ2^2])/(1600000000 x^2 \
κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 
    4 ω^2) (16 + 
    8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
 80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) + 
    4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2))) + (9.6` (κ2^2 + 
   4 ω^2))/(1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 
    4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
    8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
 80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) + 
    4 (κ2/10000 + 
       4 ω^2))) + (0.0122` (1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 + 
   80000 x κ2 (κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 
      4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 
      4 ω^2)))/(1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 
    4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
    8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
 80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
       4 ω^2) + 4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2)))
```

As you can see, the function is long but nonetheless dependent on those three paramters (I apologize if the symbols are hard to see, I copied and replaced the raw symbols with unicode glyphs from the add-on).

Now I intend to plot a density plot with the x-axis as κ2, y-axis as x, and the z-axis as the **Difference in the maxima of the function at each κ2 and x value as a function of ω**. I tried really hard to do all of this in one line through a double loop (because my computer has a hard time allocating memory). My attempt is of the following:

```
ωarr = 
Table[{i, j, 
Max[ω /. 
   NSolve[(D[f[ω, i, j], ω]) == 0 && 
     D[f[ω, i, j], {ω, 2}] < 0, Reals]] - 
 Min[ω /. 
   NSolve[(D[f[ω, i, j], ω]) == 0 && 
     D[f[ω, i, j], {ω, 2}] < 0, Reals]]}, {i, 0, 
100, 1}, {j, 0, 10^-3, 10^-4}];
```

From what I can tell, the code works and it spits out a really long nested list, each containing three elements: {i, j, maxima difference} - That's my x, y and z coordinate right there. I proceed to plot a density plot like so:

```
ListDensityPlot[ωarr]
```

But nothing comes out on the plot. I feel like I'm missing out on something trivial (I apologize since I'm a new user). I could really use any help that I can get.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of `ωarr` are wrong. You perhaps want to `Flatten[ωarr,1]`.

```
ωarr // Dimensions
```

gives
`{101,11,3}` while `ListDensityPlot` expects `{1111,3}`.

Comment: I checked my dimensions for j and indeed it was of length 11 whereas my index i is of length 101. I corrected this by changing the increments of the index j from 10^-4 to 10^-5 (you can check that the length of both i and j are now the same). 

I then did ListDensityPlot[Flatten[\[Omega]arr]] which gave me some density plot, however it has plenty of white spaces. Shouldn't the regions with a maxima difference of 0 gives a blue contour? Where are the white spaces coming from?

Comment: Length of `i` and `j` do not need to be the same, but the dataset has to have 2 dimensions instead of 3.
About the whitespace you should ask a new question after you have checked for existing answers in other topics.

Comment: I think the whitespaces are there due to your definition of `f` and not due to plotting.

Comment: I meant `f` actually gives you 0 for many values.

Comment: you must `Flatten[ warr , 1]` The one here is important so that you just flatten by one list level.

Comment: Well if I replace my \[Kappa]2 and x value in my NSolve to find just the maxima: '\[Omega]/.NSolve[(D[f[\[Omega,20,0.0006,\[Omega]) == 0 && D[f[\[Omega],20,0.0006,{\[Omega],2}]<0,Reals]', it corresponds to 0, which is indicated by the blue contour on the plot. However, replacing it by '\[Kappa]2 = 80' and 'x=0.0006' also gives a maxima of 0. However, that maxima lies on a whitespace. This is inconsistent. How is it possible?